# Auto-Layout: "center horizontally" does not seem to resolve inequality ambiguity of width/x-position, within a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

Suppose I have a `UIView` called `inner`, which is a subview of a `UICollectionViewCell`'s `Content View` in Interface Builder. The collection view uses flow layout and uses `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` to determine the size of the cell at layout time.

I want `inner` to take up the entire width of the cell, but if the cell's width is less than `6` then `inner` should be centered horizontally in the cell and have a width of `6` (`clipsToBounds` is `false` on the cell and the cell's `Content View`).

The horizontal constraints below "should" be sufficient to do this, but Interface Builder shows me two errors:

- Missing Constraints: Need constraints for: X position, width
- Inequality Constraint Ambiguity: inner.leading <= leading

Proposed horizontal constraints:

1. inner.centerX = centerX
2. inner.trailing >= trailing
3. inner.leading <= leading
4. inner.width >= 6

Why isn't this enough? Does it have something to do with the `sizeForItemAt:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface Builder's complaints might be spurious. It's better to run the app and see what happens in the View Debugger. I was able to achieve your goal like this:

- `inner` leading <= superview leading
- `inner` trailing >= superview trailing
- `inner` centerX == superview centerX
- `inner` width == 6 at a priority of 999

The results look right. The view debugger didn't complain, so I presume my settings are valid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of priority = 999, I hadn't considered using priority in this way. Yes, I think the IB errors are spurious, so I added some placeholder constraints and changed them up at runtime.